# Optimize ensemble model weights with for loop

Tags: r, optimization, ensemble-learning

i have three model probability predictions `mod.p1, mod.p2, mod.p3`

```
require(Runuran)
mod.p1<- urnorm(n = 1000, mean = 0.2, sd = 0.35, lb = 0, ub = 1)
mod.p2<- urnorm(n = 1000, mean = 0.23, sd = 0.37, lb = 0, ub = 1)
mod.p3 = urnorm(n = 1000, mean = 0.19, sd = 0.39, lb = 0, ub = 1)
```

final outcomes is given in verdict ( Yes , No )

```
Verdict <- sample( c("yes","No"), 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.2,0.8) )
```

I have three weights for each model

```
i1=0.3
i2=0.3
i3=0.4
```

creating ensemble predictions and calculating auc

```
  Ensemble=i1*mod.p1+i2*mod.p2+i3*mod.p3
  require(ROCR)    
  Ensemble.pred = prediction(Ensemble, Verdict)
  Ensemble.auc = as.numeric(performance(Ensemble.pred, "auc")@y.values)
  Ensemble.auc # 0.52
```

Now how do i write a for loop to try out different values of `i1 , i2 and i3` , and return best possible values of `i1 , i2 and i3` which give me maximum AUC.

Comment: you might be looking for `expand.grid`

Comment: the models aren't built in `caret`  , hence looking for a for loop kind of function which iterates over different weights between 0-1 for i1 , i2, & i3 and finding which i1,i2,i3 give max AUC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it , this is what i was looking at -

```
# creation of Dummy data
mod.p1<- urnorm(n = 1000, mean = 0.2, sd = 0.35, lb = 0, ub = 1)
mod.p2<- urnorm(n = 1000, mean = 0.23, sd = 0.37, lb = 0, ub = 1)
mod.p3 = urnorm(n = 1000, mean = 0.19, sd = 0.39, lb = 0, ub = 1)
Verdict <- sample( c("yes","No"), 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.2,0.8) )

#loop for optimizing the weights in ensemble
auc = 0
i1 = 0
i2 = 0
i3 = 0

for(i in seq(0,1,0.05))  {
  for (j in seq(0,1-i,0.05))  {
    k = 1-i-j
    e = i1*mod.p1 + i2*mod.p2 + i3*mod.p3
    Ensemble.pred = prediction(e, Verdict)
    Ensemble.auc = as.numeric(performance(Ensemble.pred, "auc")@y.values)
    if (Ensemble.auc>auc)  {
      auc = Ensemble.auc
      i1 = i
      i2 = j
      i3 = k
      pred = e
    }
  }
}

# get final values
auc #0.524
i1  #0
i2  #0.1
i3  #0.9
```

Answer (score 1):

Adapted this version to apply the constraints and to explore in 0.1 increments. This uses a slightly brute force way to restrict the parameters but makes it a little more general

```
require(Runuran)
require(ROCR)    

mod.p1<- urnorm(n = 1000, mean = 0.2, sd = 0.35, lb = 0, ub = 1)
mod.p2<- urnorm(n = 1000, mean = 0.23, sd = 0.37, lb = 0, ub = 1)
mod.p3 = urnorm(n = 1000, mean = 0.19, sd = 0.39, lb = 0, ub = 1)

## creating ensemble predictions and calculating auc

# make the examples reproducible
set.seed = 123  

# expand.grid, in base R, returns a dataframe
grid <- expand.grid(
  i1 = seq(0.1, 1, by=0.1),
  i2 = seq(0.1, 1, by=0.1),
  i3 = seq(0.1, 1, by=0.1))

# apply contraints to the grid
grid <- grid[(grid$i1 + grid$i2 + grid$i3) == 1,] 

Ensembles <- list()
grid$auc <- NA

for (i in 1:nrow(grid)) {
  # final outcomes is given in verdict ( Yes , No )
  Verdict <- sample( c("yes","No"), 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.2,0.8) )
  this_set <- grid[i,]
  Ensemble=(this_set[["i1"]]*mod.p1) + (this_set[["i2"]]*mod.p2) + (this_set[["i3"]]*mod.p3)
  Ensemble.pred = prediction(Ensemble, Verdict)
  Ensemble.auc = as.numeric(performance(Ensemble.pred, "auc")@y.values)
  grid$auc[i] <- Ensemble.auc
  Ensembles[i] <- list(Ensemble)
}

# print the best value (note there is some other sourc
# of randomness so
# result svary form run to run)
grid[grid$auc == max(grid$auc),]

#    i1  i2  i3      auc
# 8 0.8 0.1 0.1 0.554802
```

Comment: i1,i2,i3 are weights ( totaling up to 1 ) , how do i optimize over all possible values they can hold ? like a (0.1, 0.8, 0.1) or a (0.30,0.50,0.20) or numerous other combinations of weights

Comment: This seems to be a better approach because as per my code , i think the first instance it reaches where calculated auc < the previous auc , it stops there and tags the previous auc as maximum which may not be true.

Answer (score 0):

Your own proposed solution is actually pretty good I think. Only thing I don't understand is why you don't substitute the `i,j,k` values in the `e = i1*mod.p1 + i2*mod.p2 + i3*mod.p3` line. I would adjust like below, and this works fine.

```
for(i in seq(0,1,0.03))  {
    for (j in seq(0,1-i,0.03))  {
        k = 1-i-j
        e = i*mod.p1 + j*mod.p2 + k*mod.p3
        Ensemble.pred = prediction(e, Verdict)
        Ensemble.auc = as.numeric(performance(Ensemble.pred, "auc")@y.values)
        if (Ensemble.auc>auc)  {
            auc = Ensemble.auc
            i1 = i
            i2 = j
            i3 = k
            pred = e
        }
    }
}

# get final values
auc #0.543
i1  #0.84
i2  #0.15
i3  #0.01
```

Comment: i think the drawback is the first instance it reaches where calculated auc < the previous auc , it stops there and tags the previous auc as maximum( referring to second `if` statement) as it hasn't calculated many remaining combinations.  , am i correct there in my understanding ?

Comment: @Prateek, I dont' think i agree with your comment -- it continues executing. add a `cat` or `print` statement to be sure The one advantage with my approach is that every result is saved in a dataframe. This lets you inspect all the results after execution, not just the single maximum.

Comment: No it continues executing, it just skips the body of the `if` statement. You can explicitly break a `for` loop with the `break` statement.